# The score of a dynamic model is a martingale difference sequence

Tags: time-series, distributions, maximum-likelihood, modeling

I am going to write down some parts of *Dynamic models for volatility and heavy tails* by Andrew Harvey (2008) with my comments in bold and then ask for an alternative explanation of the final part.

Suppose initally that there is just one parameter, $\theta$, in a static model.
Define
$$u_t = k \partial \ln f(y_t ; \theta) / \partial \theta, \qquad t = 1, \dots, T$$

where k is a finite constant.
The derivative $\partial \ln f(y_t ; \theta) / \partial \theta$ is a random variable which has zero mean at the true parameter value $\theta_0$. (**I thought it was just a function of $\theta$ that obtained the max at the true parameter value not an actual random variable** )

Now let $\theta = \theta_{t |t-1}$ evolve over time as a function of past observations and past values of the score of the conditional distribution. Because the conditional score depends on past observations through $\theta_{t | t- 1}$, it can be broken down into two parts (**chain rule**).

$$\frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \psi)}{\partial \psi} = \frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \psi)}{\partial \theta_{t|t-1}} \frac{\partial \theta_{t|t-1}}{\partial \psi}$$

where the notation $f_t(y_t; \theta_{t|t-1})$ indicates that the distribution of $y_t$ depends on the time varying parameter $\theta_{t|t-1}$ and $\psi$ denotes the vector of parameters governing the dynamics.
Because $\theta_{t|t-1}$ and its derivatives depend only on past information, the distribution of the score conditional on information at time $t-1$ is the same as its unconditional distribution and so it is time invariant.
Moreover 
$$\frac{\partial f_t(y_t| Y_{t-1}; \psi)}{\partial \theta_{t|t-1}} \frac{\partial \theta_{t|t-1}}{\partial \psi}$$
is a martingale difference sequence because the derivative of the time-varying parameter $\frac{\partial \theta_{t|t-1}}{\partial \psi}$ is fixed at time $t-1$, and the expected value of the score in the static model is zero.

I start not following properly from "Because  $\theta_{t|t-1}$ and its derivatives..." to the end. Could I have a clearer explanation of these last lines? maybe more mathematical statements and less words could be useful to me.